# Is there a conformal transformation that maps the skull of Panthera tigris to the one of Panthera leo?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, theoretical-biology, anatomy

While visiting the Museum of Natural History in Rouen a few months ago, I was stunned by the similarity between the skulls of Panthera tigris and Panthera Leo: the overall shapes were very similar and only distances between homologous parts seemed to vary. As I'm into math, I wondered if this similarity could be explained by some conformal transformation mapping the skull of one species to the one of the other. Are there clues about such geometric correspondences between related species?

Comment: Have a look at [D'Arcy Thompson's work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Growth_and_Form).